# Sending SMS from inner class using SmsManager is not working

Tags: java, android, android-sms

**UPDATE:** if I take `sendSms()` function outside the inner class it works!
but I need it inside. Can someone help?

I'm trying to send sms in backgroud using `SmsManager` and nothing happens. when I go to Logcat it says:

`E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe`

I've tested it on both emulator and real device

This is a part of`MainActivity.java`:

```
 SmsReceiver.bindListener(new SmsListener() {
     @Override
     public void messageReceived(String messageText, String sender) {
          if (msgClassifier.isUrgent(messageText, null, null)) {
               sendNotification(messageText);
          }
          else {
               if(sharedPrefs.getAutoReplyState(getApplication())){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "send sms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sendSms(sender,messageText);

               }

          }
     }
 });




 public void sendSms(String number, String msg){
     android.telephony.SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
     smsManager.sendTextMessage(number,null,msg,null,null);
 }
```

The Toast is being showed and I have also printed `sender` and `messageText` and it prints what it should print so this is not the problem.
I have been looking for this error and tried to clean project, rebuild, exit android and nothing worked.

**I have included SEND_SMS permission in Manifest**

Comment: have you included sms permission in you app

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to mention it

Comment: art error occurs when there is no connection between the server adb and client device , have you tried killing the adb ? Also delete the build folder and try again

Comment: Yes, I have tried it now and it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg) {
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I realized that if I take sendSms function out of the inner class it works.
Does anyone know how Can I still leave it inside?

Comment: I suspect you're probably using a static function that's why it won't let you sendSms within the function.  Have you checked on this `SmsManager.getDefault()` part if taken out?

Comment: sendSMS is not static and it us called from onCreate. I have tried to put SmsManager.getDefault() out and it didn't help